# actionscript transparent textinput background

Tags: actionscript-3, background, transparent, textinput

after hours of search I successfully set my font color to yellow, but I still can`t figure out how to make my background of textinput transparent  :(
(I dragged it out of the component window) 
What is wrong with my code?

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.size = 10;
tf.color = 0xFFF000;
nameField.setStyle("textFormat", tf);

nameField.alpha = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nameField.background = false;` you should check the docs.

as in following example

```
var input:TextField = new TextField();
input.textColor = 0xFFFF00;
input.background = false;
input.backgroundColor = 0x000000;//this is to show that the background is not visible - you can put any colour other than SWF's background:)
input.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;

addChild(input);
```

Comment: are you sure:) that background is part of the textfield? and not for example a shape/sprite beneath?

Answer (score 3):

TextInput has styles **contentBackgroundAlpha** and **contentBackgroundColor**.

```
nameField.setStyle("contentBackgroundAlpha", 0);
```

P.S. It is if you use FLEX.

Comment: I dunno what Flex is  :(  okay I`ve just googled it. Is it some kind of a "must-have" for AS3 programmers? Should I download it?

Comment: not must have - it's anpther way to program in AS, FLash IDE, Flex and pure ActionScript with 3rd party editor and Flex SDK to comile.